# Combining the result of two queries using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, union, sql-except

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
Table A             Table B
| a | b | c |       | a | b | c |
|---|---|---|       |---|---|---|
| a | b | c |       | a | b | c |
| a | c | d |       | a | c | d |
| c | d | e |       | a | b | c |
| f | g | h |       | o | p | q |
| a | a | a |       | a | b | c |
```

and I want to find all the rows that differ from both tables.

This gives me the rows from A that are not in B:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM A
EXCEPT 
SELECT a, b, c FROM B;

| a | b | c |
|---|---|---|
| a | a | a |
| c | d | e |
| f | g | h |
```

and this gives me the rows from B that are not in A:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM B
EXCEPT 
SELECT a, b, c FROM A;

| a | b | c |
|---|---|---|
| o | p | q |
```

So to combine the two I tried using

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM A
EXCEPT 
SELECT a, b, c FROM B
UNION
SELECT a, b, c FROM B
EXCEPT 
SELECT a, b, c FROM A;
```

but it still only gives me the rows from B.

How do I get rows from both tables, like this?

```
| a | b | c |
|---|---|---|
| a | a | a |
| c | d | e |
| f | g | h |
| o | p | q |
```

Comment: Did you try using parentheses `()` for each EXCEPT statement?

Comment: Yes, that gives me `Error: near "(": syntax error`.

Comment: Just use `SELECT * FROM` outside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try enclosing the individual except in parentheses and then do the union:

```
select * from (
    select a, b, c from a
    except 
    select a, b, c from b
)
union
select * from (
    select a, b, c from b
    except 
    select a, b, c from a
);
```